# Вывести массив Angular?

Tags: angularstrap, angularjs

В контроллере обозначен массив:

```
$scope.messages = [];
```

Далее в этом же контроллере метод заполняющий массив:

```
$scope.getItems = function(arr){
     angular.forEach(arr, function(item) {
           $scope.messages.push(item);
     });
  console.log($scope.messages);
}
```

В шаблоне HTML пытаюсь получить значения массива:

```
<div class="form-error" ng-repat="error in messages">
   {{error}}
</div>
```

На выходе в `{{error}}` выводит пустоту

Comment: @Jony

     <div class="form-error" ng-repat="error in messages"> {{error}} </div>

Данная конструкция в области видимости Вашего контроллера?

Т.е. 

    <div ng-controller="FooController">
       ...
       <div class="form-error" ng-repat="error in messages"> {{error}} </div>
       ...
    </div>

Что выводит `console.log($scope.messages)`?

Кроме того, `$scope.getItems()` где-нибудь вызывается? Не проще ли избавиться от ней:

    var arr = ['foo', 'bar'];
    
    $scope.messages = [];
    angular.forEach(arr, function(item) {
       $scope.messages.push(item);
    });

Comment: И зачем вообще запускать `.forEach`, если можно:

   $scope.messages = arr;

Comment: Da, konecno v oblasti vidimosti

Comment: Спасибо - оказалась ошибка в синтаксисе: `ng-repeat`

Comment: @Jony: Да, я уже заметил `ng-repat`, кода [набирал Вам пример](http://jsfiddle.net/hh18e9xx/)

Comment: @Jony, Вы бы ответ на [предыдущий Ваш вопрос](http://hashcode.ru/questions/402164/angularjs-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D1%83-radio-button-%D0%B2-angular) отметили, как верный. Неважно, мой или уважаемого @zhenyab.